# Why GetAllDateTimePatterns method doesn't return unique formats?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I'm really surprised with [`DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aszyst2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not return unique standard formats.

Let me give you an example with [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

```
var pattern = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat
                          GetAllDateTimePatterns();
foreach (var format in pattern)
{
    Console.WriteLine(format);
}
```

In .NET Framework 4.5, this code will print `34` standard pattern.

When I used [`Enumerable.Distinct` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with this method;

```
var pattern = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.
                          GetAllDateTimePatterns().
                          Distinct();
foreach (var format in pattern)
{
     Console.WriteLine(format);
}
```

This code will print `29` standard patterns under the same conditions.

You can even see these duplicate patterns when you debug it;

[image]

Why this method returns same patterns multiple times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason is; because some of [standard date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) have multiple format specifiers. Such as;

- [`"M", "m"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#MonthDay)
- [`"O", "o"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Roundtrip)
- [`"R", "r"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#RFC1123)
- [`"Y", "y"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#YearMonth)

Let's look at how `GetAllDateTimePatterns` method [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformatinfo.cs#872f2bc8e4a83add);

```
public  String[] GetAllDateTimePatterns()
{
    List<String> results = new List<String>(DEFAULT_ALL_DATETIMES_SIZE);

    for (int i = 0; i < DateTimeFormat.allStandardFormats.Length; i++)
    {
        String[] strings = GetAllDateTimePatterns(DateTimeFormat.allStandardFormats[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < strings.Length; j++)
        {
            results.Add(strings[j]);
        }
    }
    return results.ToArray();
}
```

This method calls [`GetAllDateTimePatterns(char)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dah0ktz1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the all return values of `DateTimeFormat.allStandardFormats` array. And this array [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformat.cs#6ab03dfc9890cfda) as;

```
internal static char[] allStandardFormats = 
{
    'd', 'D', 'f', 'F', 'g', 'G', 
    'm', 'M', 'o', 'O', 'r', 'R', 
    's', 't', 'T', 'u', 'U', 'y', 'Y',
};
```

That's why this method and overloads will generate same formats for `m` and `M` and they added to `results` array which is the source of this method.

Besides on that reason, [`("F") Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#FullDateLongTime) and [`("U") format specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#UniversalFull) are equivalent. These are also generates same formats which is handled in [`GetAllDateTimePatterns(char)` method's impelementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformatinfo.cs#415c739c76f75777);

```
public  String[] GetAllDateTimePatterns(char format)
{
    String [] result = null;

    switch (format)
    {
        case 'd':
            result = this.AllShortDatePatterns;
            break;
        case 'D':
            result = this.AllLongDatePatterns;
            break;
        case 'f':
            result = GetCombinedPatterns(AllLongDatePatterns, AllShortTimePatterns, " ");
            break;
        case 'F':
        case 'U':
            result = GetCombinedPatterns(AllLongDatePatterns, AllLongTimePatterns, " ");
            break;
        case 'g':
            result = GetCombinedPatterns(AllShortDatePatterns, AllShortTimePatterns, " ");
            break;
        case 'G':
            result = GetCombinedPatterns(AllShortDatePatterns, AllLongTimePatterns, " ");
            break;
        case 'm':
        case 'M':
            result = new String[] {MonthDayPattern};
            break;
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
            result = new String[] {DateTimeFormat.RoundtripFormat};
            break;
        case 'r':
        case 'R':
            result = new String[] {rfc1123Pattern};
            break;
        case 's':
            result = new String[] {sortableDateTimePattern};
            break;
        case 't':
            result = this.AllShortTimePatterns;
            break;
        case 'T':
            result = this.AllLongTimePatterns;
            break;
        case 'u':
            result = new String[] {UniversalSortableDateTimePattern};
            break;
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            result = this.AllYearMonthPatterns;
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Format_BadFormatSpecifier"), "format");
    }
    return (result);
}
```

Comment: After 3 weeks, since this question didn't get any better answer, I accept mine.